# How to get this value on xml file using python? (See the xml code)

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my xml file. Settings.xml and This is what it inside have...

```
<settings>
    <setting id="ipkey" value="1252473100" />
</settings>
```

How to get ipkey value using python? I think this understandable...

Comment: Didn't tried any. I'm new to python... Searching to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to help yourself get a particular attribute.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse('yourfile.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

value = root.find('./setting').attrib['id']
```

Comment: It worked... Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

For Example with lxml http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.XML("""<settings>
...    <setting id="ipkey" value="1252473100" />
... </settings>""")
>>> tree.xpath("//setting[@id='ipkey']/@value")
['1252473100']
```

Comment: xml is saved in same directory. So how we can add that xml? Also how to print ip key value?